# Term for a single surviving copy of a printed text

Tags: single-word-requests

I know that there is a precise word which refers to a single surviving copy of a printed text, but I can't recall it or find it anywhere in my notes. Help?

Comment: "Archival copy" sorta fits your description.

Comment: I mostly see a phrase, "single/sole/only extant copy". I don't know of a single word for this, but maybe the phrase will help you in your search.

Comment: I read through the glossary of book terms on Abe Books, an antique book seller, and found nothing.  If a word for this does not exist, it should.

Comment: There is *hapax legomenon,* but that refers to a single occurrence of a **word** within a work, not a single copy of the work itself.

Comment: Printed by hand or by a printing press?

Comment: Is there any chance this is a misremembering of 'incunabula'? That being 
 books printed between the invention of moveable type and 1500, and hence pretty rare?

Comment: @HotLicks no, the existence of an archival copy implies other copies extant.

Answer (score 17):

> Unica / Unicum

[Google Definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20Unica&oq=define%20Unica&gs_l=psy-ab.12...0.0.0.185877.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.dummy_maps_web_fallback...0...1..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.yd-7KKvtFpw): a unique example or specimen.

Example use: “The concept of a unicum is difficult for the average library user to understand, since books, by their very nature, exist in more than one copy. That’s the genius of Gutenberg’s invention, after all,”

This quote is from an article explaining a University of Illinois project to scan books that exist in only one copy.  The article is [here](https://news.illinois.edu/blog/view/6367/260229)

The university project is called [Project Unica](https://digital.library.illinois.edu/collections/81346b10-e3fb-012f-c5b6-0019b9e633c5-8)

Comment: Cool -- is this word considered (by anyone other than those on the project) to be in common use?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft  Admittedly, its a new word for me.  I liked the idea of extreme rarity so much, I did some google research to find a description.  If there is something more common, hopefully someone will post it.

Comment: Google sources their definitions form oxford living dictionaries. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unicum

Comment: That a rare thing should have a rare name is to be expected,

Comment: Note that similarly to *data* and *datum*, *unica* is plural and *unicum* is singular. That's why the project name is different from the word in the quoted text. The project is about preserving all the unica.

Comment: +1 It may be worth noting, however, that this term does not necessarily imply that there ever was more than one copy; some items (and books) are *unica* from the beginning (e.g. probably the bound trial transcripts described in the linked article or a one-off illuminated manuscript).

Answer (score 3):

The German term is "das Unikat" (not limited to books), and my dictionary tells me the translation is the old and slightly obsolete english noun "unique".

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unique

Chambers 21st Century Dictionary says: "anything, especially formerly a coin or medal, of which there is only one copy"

Comment: Checking the OED, there is a citation to support this use: 1923   Inland Printer Mar. 870/1 "Several [sc. Bibles] are **uniques**, whose value can not be estimated." I would suggest including [this definition](https://books.google.com/books?id=D37Cd3Ad7eIC&pg=PA1549&lpg=PA1549&dq="of+which+there+is+only+one+example+or+copy.") in your post (it's almost the same as the one definition in the OED).

Comment: *unicum* : late 19th century: from Latin, neuter of *unicus* **‘unique.’** +1